# Using spaces inside array values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I am a self-teaching noob, so apologies for the basic nature of the question, which I imagine has been answered elsewhere! I did try to find the answer. :)

Is it possible to use spaces inside array values somehow? For example, I want to specify which friend is in each position in the array:

```
<?php
    $friends = array("John White", "Jane", "John Black" );
  ?>
```

Is there a way? Or am I misunderstanding the point of an array?

Comment: Perhaps you should read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: What do you want to achieve sorry? Yes you can use spaces inside the values, as you have done above, but I think there's another point to your question?

Comment: Certainly you can. You could easily answer that yourself: just execute your own code. Does it throw any errors? No. So the answer is: you can.

Comment: Sorry, can't follow there. First: spaces in strings are obviously valid, strings would make little sense without that. If such string is contained in an array or elsewhere does not alter or influence that fact. An array is nothing but a "collection" of entries, typically strings. About your example in the last comment: that is confusing, since it still _does_ contain blanks in the strings...

Comment: @arkascha thank you for taking the time to respond. I am taking a php class on Codecademy and I tried executing the code above with spaces in array values, but it told me there was an error. When I removed the spaces and wrote simply: 

<?php 
         $friends = array("JohnWhite", "Jane", "JohnBlack" );
   ?>

Then it accepted my code. I thought maybe there was a rule about spaces and I couldn't see anything in the documentation or previous questions as Tristan and Chris Evans suggested.

It was obviously a stupid question but I wasn't sure of that at the time... ;)

Comment: deleted the previous response by mistake instead of editing! d'oh!

Comment: @Tristan - thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @ChrisEvans - thanks for clarifying. Perhaps there is a bug on Codeacademy but there was nothing on the forum there either.

Comment: There is no such thing as a stupid question. Some question may appear like that afterwards. But unless someone switches off his brain by purpose we can all safely assume for all questions that people ask to the best of their knowledge at that time. All fine. However I would be interested to see that class definition so that we can reproduce that error message. Because it sounds quite strange to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use spaces in your arrays values like this:

```
$description=array("PHP is a programming language");
```

and you can search in arrays values text for finding your friend name or family:

```
$result=strpos($description[0],"PHP");
```

if strpos find your search needle return position of it and if not found return false:
for checking false you can use

```
if ($pos === false) {
//do some thing
}else{
// don some thing
}
```

[array refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

[strpos refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)